# Has Turing's invention of Turing machines contributed to the development of real computers?

Tags: computer-science, computers, computer-scientists, turing

Has Turing's invention of Turing machines contributed to the development of real computers, which resulted in the personal computers we currently use?

I often saw it mentioned that this is an important contribution of mathematical logic to the real world, but Turing machines are just a very theoretical model of computation, so I don't see why this should influence the development of *real* computers.

Comment: Yes; see [Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing#Career_and_research): "Between 1945 and 1947, Turing  worked on the design of the ACE (Automatic Computing Engine) at the National Physical Laboratory (NPL). He presented a paper on 19 February 1946, which was the first detailed design of a stored-program computer."

Comment: And see [Turing and Von Neumann](https://www.gresham.ac.uk/lectures-and-events/turing-and-von-neumann)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My question was whether Turing's *invention of Turing machines* contributed to the development of real computers. *Not* whether his work on ACE has contributed to that.

Comment: The concept of the Turing machine is fundamental to thinking about computation and programming.

Comment: @JonCuster Of course it's fundamental in theoretical computer science. I repeat my question, to be clear: Has Turing's invention of Turing machines contributed to the development of real computers? That's a different question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284/what-is-turing-complete would be a start. Turing established one of the main pillars of computer science.

Comment: I think you need to clarify just what you are asking. Thinking about designing a computer without knowing what ‘computing’ is actually about is really hard. Did Turing design a microprocessor? No. Randomly coming up with a circuit that ‘computes’ is a long random walk through the wilderness.

Comment: I thnk you are trying to split the unsplittable. Working out in detail an imaginary scheme for storage, retrieval, programming and processing shaped the design of real computers by both Turing and von Neumann, among others. The Turing machine was a structural blueprint of von Neumann architecture, which was then embodied in first programmable computers like EDVAC, see [Development of the stored-program concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture#Development_of_the_stored-program_concept).

Comment: @Conifold So is the answer yes?

Comment: It is hard to tell from the post and the comments what meaning of "contributed" you have in mind, but it would be yes on my understanding of it.

Comment: Question #1 for any machine language: Can it simulate a Turing machine? If not, back to the drawing board.